# Uncaught TypeError in php while compiling code online

Tags: php

I am trying to run a very simple code on a php online compiler but everytime it gives me an error: Here is the [link](https://3v4l.org/T15Hr)

```
<?php

function value(integer $h) {
    if(!is_int($h)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('integer expected');
    }
    if($h <= 7) {
        throw new RangeException('integer should be greater than 7');
    }
    echo $h;
    return $return;
}

$something = value(11111);
echo $something;
```

Below is the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to value() must be an instance of integer, integer given,
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use type `int` instead `integer` in function.

In PHP type named `int` not `integer`